# Is there a way to optimize or maybe even vectorize this? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, optimization, vectorization

I have an `if` statement within two loops, it runs too slow and I think it can be optimized. `NF_zeta` is a 2D logical array.

```
for k = 2:Nx
    for l = 2:Ny
        if NF_zeta(l,k)
            z2(l,k) = z1(l,k) - optVar2*(U2(l,k) - U2(l,k-1) + V2(l,k) - V2(l-1,k));
        end
    end
end
```

Here are the results of a profiler
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwHLM.png

I tried with single loop in which the conditional statement was taken care of. Something similar to what is done for one loop `for [1 4 5]`, I wrote

```
for idx = NF_zeta_v
    z2(idx(1),idx(2)) = z1(idx(1),idx(2)) - optVar2*(U2(idx(1),idx(2)) - U2(idx(1),idx(2)-1) + V2(idx(1),idx(2)) - V2(idx(1)-1,idx(2)));
end
```

where `NF_zeta_v` is created in advance like this

```
c_z = 1;
for l = 1:Ny
    for k = 1:Nx
        if NF_zeta(l,k)
           NF_zeta_v(:,c_z) = [l;k];
           c_z = c_z + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

It took almost twice as long. The results of a profiler https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G8mO.png

What else can I try, any suggestions?

Comment: What are the datasizes of the relevant inputs?

Comment: @Divakar `Ny = 2210` and `Nx = 927`

Comment: @Divakar do you mean how many `true`s are in `NF_zeta`?, if that's what you mean `sum(sum(NF_zeta)) = 1280456`. If you mean something else please explain.

Comment: Inputs seem to be `z1`, `optVar2`, `U2`, `V2`. See if I missed out on listing any other **relevant** inputs. So what are their sizes?

Comment: @Divakar `z1`, `U2` and `V2` are all 2210x927. `optVar2` is just a scalar, it's not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one vectorized solution using [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) -

```
diffs = diff(U2(2:end,:),[],2) + diff(V2(:,2:end),[],1);
allvals = z1(2:end,2:end) - optVar2*diffs;
z2(2:Ny,2:Nx) = NF_zeta(2:Ny,2:Nx).*allvals;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this if `N_x` and `N_y` are the size values:

```
Z2 = (z1-optVar2*(U2-circshift(U2, [0 1])+V2-circshift(V2, [1 0]))).*(double(NF_zeta));
Z2(1,:) = 0;
Z2(:,1) = 0;
```